# Received a call with arguments [ '', undefined ] but all configured strategies specify other arguments

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

It's weird. In the following code I have tried to pass different arguments to the Get2 method and none seems to work, even with the defined types. Do you have any idea what may be going on?

**ERROR**

```
Spy 'PictureService.get2' received a call with arguments [ '', undefined ] but all configured strategies specify other arguments.
```

**CODE**

**SPEC**

```
let pictureService: jasmine.SpyObj<PictureService>
    
        beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
            pictureService = jasmine.createSpyObj('PictureService', ['Get1', 'Get2']);
            pictureService.get1.and.returnValue(of(value1));
            pictureService.get2.withArgs('string1', 'string2').and.returnValue(of('string3'));
        ......
```

**OR**

```
pictureService.get2.withArgs('string1', null).and.returnValue(of('string3'));
```

**OR**

```
pictureService.get2.withArgs('string1', undefined).and.returnValue(of('string3'));
```

**OR**

```
let val:any
pictureService.get2.withArgs('string1', val).and.returnValue(of('string3'));
```

**TS**

```
this.picture.get2('string1', 'string2').subscribe(
                        response => {
                            if (response) {
                                this.image = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + response;
                            }
                        },
    .......
```

Comment: looks like when your function `get2` gets called in your component's file it receives the args `''` (empty string) and `undefined` which is not a case you have "registered" with `withArgs()`. You need to figure out why your function is getting those args which you (presumably) don't expect

Comment: @Sleepwalker. But I am not using specifically this function in my SPEC file. It is defined in TS as I show you and I define the spy as I show you. I can´t figure it out where I call this function passing '' and undefined as parameters.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the first time I am seeing `withArgs`, I usually use `callFake`.

If you are always going to return the same value, you can change `withArgs` to `returnValue`.

```
pictureService.get2.and.returnValue(of('string3'));
```

If you would like flexibility with the arguments, you can try using `callFake`.

```
pictureService.get2.withArgs('string1', 'string2').and.callFake((string1, string2) => {
  if (string1 && string2) {
    return of('string3');
  }
  return of('string4');
});
```

I find `callFake` more flexible with the arguments.